# Чему соответствуют знаки препинания при косвенной речи в кавычках ?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Он сказал лишь о том, что «бензин есть и они его отпускают».

Если бы не кавычки, то запятую перед *и* не надо было бы ставить. Но при цитировании слов: "Бензин есть, и они его отпускают" - запятая остается?

Answer (score 4):

Цитирование не меняет структуру сложноподчинённого предложения с двумя однородными придаточными, поэтому запятой нет. Нужно смотреть не на часть предложения, а на предложение в целом.

Answer (score 1):

Он сказал, что, "возможно, приедет".

Правильно ли здесь стоит запятая после *что*?

Ведь, например, в предложении *Но вот пришло время, когда «старик, одержимый рисунком» уже не мог держать кисть.* Розенталь рекомендует не ставить запятую после кавычек.

Comment: Вы чуть-чуть не дочитали Розенталя:запятая не ставится ни перед закрывающимися кавычками, ни после них.Запятая НЕ ОПУСКАЕТСЯ перед открывающимися кавычками, например: Вспомните, "как хороши, как свежи были розы".У Вас перед открывающимися, значит, запятая есть.

Answer (score 1):

Данную тему желательно рассмотреть на более жизненных (естественных) примерах, для чего предлагается рассмотреть  цитаты из произведений Л.Н. Толстого.

(1) Поправляя этюд ученика, Брюллов в нескольких местах чуть тронул его, и плохой, мертвый этюд вдруг ожил.  “Вот, чуть-чуть тронули, и все изменилось”, - заметил один из учеников. 
Можно предположить, что косвенная речь будет выглядеть следующим образом:  Один из учеников заметил, что « вот, чуть-чуть тронули, и все изменилось”.

(2)  И потому, за исключением первых, все романы Мопассана слабы.
Косвенная речь: Толстой считал, что «за исключением первых, все романы Мопассана слабы».

ВЫВОД:
Наверное, можно утверждать следующее.

1) Знаки препинания, находящиеся  в начале и в конце цитируемого текста,  не входят в цитату (об этом говорится в правилах Розенталя).

2) Внутри цитаты все знаки сохраняются,  то есть цитата рассматривается как единое целое и структура предложения не влияет на ее внутренние знаки.

Comment: Значит, Он сказал лишь о том, что «бензин есть, и они его отпускают»?

Comment: Это значит только по логике вещей, но я не могу найти прямого указания на эту ситуацию в правилах. А  приведенная фраза не очень хороша тем, что в подобных случаях кавычки вообще не ставятся, то есть цитирование обычно не применяется: Он сказал лишь о том, что бензин есть и они его отпускают.При цитировании "он" как бы исключается из "они", и поэтому вся фраза с "он-они" становится неясной. В общем, цитирование - это не для разговорной речи.

Comment: Формально здесь следующая ситуация. Прямая речь: Он сказал: "Бензин есть, и они его отпускают". Косвенная речь: Он сказал, что "бензин есть, и они его отпускают".  Для того, чтобы не ставить запятые, надо найти такое указание в правилах. Фактически это редактирование цитаты, и правило должно регулировать возможности такого редактирования". Если правила нет, то логичнее сохранить знаки.

Answer (score 0):

Если при цитировании это предложение синтаксически связано с предложением, то мы пишем со строчной буквы и заключаем цитату в кавычки.

Розенталь также считал, что "язык может изменит человека". Постскриптум: это я сам придумал =)

Цитата также может быть оформлена при помощи прямой речи, например: Женя как-то раз сказал: "Люблю я эти игры!".